# Linq SQL - How to use GroupBy Clause in linq even when i don't need aggregate function

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have admission table which contains the following data :

```
          Std_Id     Name     Class
          1          ali       one
          2          jack      two
          3          adam      one
          4          john      two
          5          tris      one
          6          bill      two-I
          7          sarah     one-I
          8          josh      two-I
          9          alex      one-I
```

I want to show the list such that the record having the same class must be shown consecutively ,something like this :

```
          Std_Id     Name     Class

          2          jack      two
          4          john      two

          1          ali       one
          3          adam      one
          5          tris      one

          6          bill      two-I
          8          josh      two-I

          7          sarah     one-I
          9          alex      one-I
```

How can i create the above list using linq.I'm using entity framework 6.0.
This is what i'm trying...

```
    db.Admissions.GroupBy(d=>d.ClassId).ToList();
```

Comment: I think you would need an `OrderBy` instead of a `GroupBy`.

Comment: Order by class.

Comment: thanks.it works great....   :-):-):-)

Comment: Or you can use dictionary instead:  `db.Admissions.GroupBy(d=>d.ClassId).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());`. It has certain advantages over `List`

Comment: What kind of advantages using dictionary over list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Db.Admissions.OrderBy(od=>od.ClassID)
```